# TYPO3 12 - Custom Login after Registration

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-12.x

I have my own extension to perform a user registration. After a successful registration I want to log in the user automatically.

in the past I have used the following script, which no longer works under TYPO3 12:

```
$userToLogin = 42; // userId after registration

$feUser = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user;
unset($feUser->user);
$feUser->createUserSession($userToLogin);
$feUser->loginSessionStarted = TRUE;
$feUser->user = $feUser->fetchUserSession();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
```

i have already implemented an auth service, but it is not called automatically after registration:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addService(
    'bo_xyz',
    'auth',
    \VENDOR\Extension\Service\MyAuthService::class,
    array(
        'title' => 'My Authentication',
        'description' => '',

        'subtype' => 'authUserFE',

        'available' => true,
        'priority' => 60,
        'quality' => 50,

        'os' => '',
        'exec' => '',

        'className' => \VENDOR\Extension\Service\MyAuthService::class
    )
);
```

in the class `MyAuthService` is the function `authUser()`, but this is not called. i pass the logintype=login via POST with.
how can i make the service run? do you have any tips for automatic login based on a users uid?

**SOLUTION**
After some research/tests i have found a solution by myself, this works for me:

```
$feUser = $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user;
unset($feUser->user);
$sessionResult = $feUser->createUserSession(['uid' => 42]);
$feUser->loginSessionStarted = TRUE;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->loginUser = 1;
setcookie("fe_typo_user", $sessionResult->getJwt(), 0, '/');
```

Comment: Take a look to existing user register extensions which provides such a feature, e.g. femanager (https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/femanager)

Comment: i have already looked at the extension. in particular the login(User $user, $storagePids = null) function from the UserUtility class. but this no longer works under typo3 12 because the AbstractUserAuthentication::fetchUserSession() function no longer exists.

Comment: by generating a userSession and  saving a manual cookie it works for me. see "Solution"