# TYPO3 Login FrontendUser from BE Context

Tags: typo3

what is the easiest way to login an fe_user from BE in TYPO3 v12?

After reading the documentation I am a little bit confused which method I should use:

- AuthenticationService
- FrontendUserAuthentication
- UserSessionManager

Previous to TYPO3 v12 I used a Middleware which calls:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->createUserSession($user_db);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user = $user_db;
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->setKey('ses', $cookieName, $user_db);
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchGroupData();
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->fetchUserSession();
```

and made a redirect to the target page.

When I am using UserSessionManager, the FE user is set in the $GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user,
but after the redirect the user is not logged in :disappointed: (missing cookie/session ?)

Answer (score 0):

Found an solution:

```
            $frontendUser = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Authentication\FrontendUserAuthentication::class);
            $frontendUser->start($request);
            $session = $frontendUser->createUserSession($user);
            $frontendUser->storeSessionData();
            setcookie("fe_typo_user", $session->getJwt(), 0, '/');
```

Hint from:
[TYPO3 12 - Custom Login after Registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76680154/typo3-12-custom-login-after-registration)